# Qtoolbar buttons are not expanding

Tags: c++, linux, qt, toolbar

In mainwindow, it has a toolbar which buttons are expanding but another toolbar buttons are not expading why?? 
First toolbar function is directly calling in mainwindow constructor but another toolbar function is calling like `setCentralWidget(eicWidgetController());` So can anyone tell me the proper solution fot it?

Comment: Any one can give me solution for it?

Comment: solution for it @t.m.